# Django JSON Error - "This field is required"

Tags: arrays, nested, field, restkit, django-rest-framework

I have generated the correct json output for my service. I've copied and pasted the restkit output in the browser for the restservice and it works just fine. However, I get

```
{"questions": ["This field is required."]}
```

for my nested array field for the response from the RKResponsDescriptor when trying to post from restkit. My post works if I take away the questions relationship. I can't understand why the post won't work if my json format is correct with all of the correct fields.  I am using django-rest-framework for the rest service.

How do I post the questions field successfully from Restkit?

Here's my json from Restkit.

```
{
 "questions" : [
    {
      "question_text" : "What is the question text?",
      "question_description" : "What is the question?",
      "driver_id" : 9
    }
  ],
  "id" : 9,
  "first_name" : "Mark",
  "phone" : "6783333333",
  "last_name" : "Cuban",
  "city" : "Decatur",
  "email" : "cuban@gmail.com",
  "home_address" : "3144 Topawa Pl.",
  "state" : "Florida",
  "zipcode" : "30033"
}
```

Here's my mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *driverMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Driver" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

[driverMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"id":@"driverID", @"email":@"email", @"last_name":@"lastName", @"first_name":@"firstName", @"phone":@"phone", @"home_address":@"homeAddress", @"city":@"city", @"state":@"state", @"zipcode":@"zip"}];

driverMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"driverID"];

RKEntityMapping *questionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Question" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

[questionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"driver_id":@"driver.driverID",@"question_description":@"questionDescription", @"question_text":@"questionText"}];


[driverMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"questions" toKeyPath:@"questions" withMapping:questionMapping]];


NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:driverMapping
                                                                                     pathPattern:@"/drivers/"
                                                                                        keyPath:nil
                                                                                    statusCodes:statusCodes];
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:driverMapping objectClass:[Driver class] rootKeyPath:nil];

[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

Here's my request sent to the server. I used Charles to retrieve this.

```
  city    Decatur
  email   cuban@gmail.com
  first_name      Mark
  home_address    3144 Topawa Pl.
  id      9
  last_name   Cuban
  phone   6783333333
  questions[][driver_id]    9
  questions[][question_description] What is the question?
  questions[][question_text]    What is the question text?
  state   Florida
  zipcode  30033
```

Here's the raw data from Charles.

```
   POST /drivers/ HTTP/1.1
   Host: localhost:8888
   Authorization: Basic andoaW5lczpXZWJzdGVycGllMQ==
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Accept-Language: en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5
   Accept: application/json
   Content-Length: 304
   Connection: keep-alive
   User-Agent: mydriver/1.0 (iPad Simulator; iOS 6.1; Scale/2.00)

 city=Decatur&email=cuban%40gmail.com&first_name=Mark&home_address=3144%20Topawa%20Pl.&id=9&last_name=Cuban&phone=6783333333&questions[][driver_id]=9&questions[][question_description]=What%20is%20the%20question%3F&questions[][question_text]=What%20is%20the%20question%20text%3F&state=Florida&zipcode=30033
```

Comment: Ask a question, it's unclear what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I've updated with a question.

Comment: Your "JSON from RestKit", how did you get it? Is it the JSON that actually hits the wire or your source object? Show your mappings and response descriptors.

Comment: @Wain That's the json from the object that gets parse from RKObjectParameterization. I believe the json hits the wire.

Comment: Use the `Charles` proxy or similar to see what actually hits the wire

Comment: Usually when creating a request descriptor you'd use the inverse mapping...

Comment: @Wain Got the proxy above. Looks like I'm sending 3 separate question fields. Not sure why it's sending that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear if you're actually sending JSON as the data you paste in from Charles is in no particular format. Check the headers and the "JSON text" tab (if it exists).

Also, change your request descriptor:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[driverMapping inverseMapping] objectClass:[Driver class] rootKeyPath:nil];
```

Comment: The json tab doesn't exist. I was able to get the raw data. It's post above.

Comment: So you aren't sending JSON. Are you setting `requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;` on your object manager?

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. You saved my life. Once I added the requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMTypeJSON; the json was produced.